# Keycloak 21.1.2: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find ScriptEngine for script

Tags: javascript, java, keycloak

I am using quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.2 docker image with Java script adapters, I get below error when the Javascript adapters are executed in the authentication flow

> keycloak-1 keycloak 2023-09-26 11:19:33,012 WARN
> [org.keycloak.services] (executor-thread-5) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed
> authentication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find
> ScriptEngine for script: Script{id='null', realmId='master',
> name='role-based-authenticator', type='text/javascript',
> code='AuthenticationFlowError =
> Java.type("org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowError");

But as per release notes at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/index.html#keycloak-21-1-0 version 21.1.0 onwards Nashorn javascript engine is available in Keycloak server by default, but for some reason this does not work. How can i fix this?

### Update 05.10.23

I tried reproducing with below code, it seems to work fine. Issue should be there in our custom build which is a bit complicated which i cannot share it here.

##### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  keycloak:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
      - KC_FEATURES=scripts
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: "false"
      KC_FEATURES: scripts
    command:
      - start-dev
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

##### Dockerfile

```
ARG KEYCLOAK_VERSION=21.1.2

FROM redhat/ubi8-minimal:8.6-941 as bundle

# Stage to avoid zip in final image and git repository
RUN microdnf install -y findutils zip
COPY keycloak-extensions /tmp/keycloak-extensions

WORKDIR /tmp/keycloak-extensions
RUN find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -execdir /bin/sh -c "cd {}; zip -r \"/tmp/keycloak-extensions/{}.jar\" ." \;


# Build Step
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:$KEYCLOAK_VERSION as builder

ARG KC_FEATURES

# Copy Keycloak extensions and metrics provider
COPY --from=bundle /tmp/keycloak-extensions/*.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/

# Build optimized keycloak image
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:$KEYCLOAK_VERSION

ARG KC_FEATURES

COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
CMD [ "start"]
```

##### Keycloak adapter code

###### keycloak-extensions/log-autenticator/log-authenticator.js

```
function authenticate(context) {
    LOG.info("Hello World!");
    context.success();
}
```

###### keycloak-extensions/log-autenticator/META-INF/keycloak-scripts.json

```
{
  "authenticators": [
    {
      "name": "log-authenticator",
      "fileName": "log-authenticator.js",
      "description": "Logs a simple Hello message"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide steps on how to reproduce this for a quicker resolution?

Comment: Are you sure you're using 21.1.2 and not 21.0? I can't reproduce the issue on 21.1.2. There is more info on it here, BTW - https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/17671

Comment: @AnishB. I will try to create a simple use case to reproduce this and share here later

Comment: @Sirish Kindly do it before the bounty ends. :) I have taken the docker instance and running it on my local and I'm just stuck at the adapter part to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @mvmn I checked again, we are using 21.1.2.

Comment: @mvmn I have updated my question with the documentation reference you have provided. Should some issue with our build. If you can post your answer as solution, i will accept it.

Comment: @Sirish, thanks, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was present in Keycloak 21.0 because it didn't include Nashorn JavaScript engine in it's distribution. But in 21.1.2 Keycloak has included Nashorn as a part of distribution.

See more at
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/17671

Comment: After further analysis in our deployment , JAVA_OPTS was causing this issue. We are using JAVA_OPTS set to -server -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman .After removing Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman from the JAVA_OPTION it seems to work. But i am not sure what are the implications of making this change.

Comment: AFAIK option jboss.modules.system.pkgs should not have any effect as Keycloak 21.1.2 is based on quarkus and this option is specific to Wildfly distribution.